# Tracking conversion rate on wizard form

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I have a multistep wizard form, but in my case is not a with different pages, the wizard form is all in one using jQuery.
My question is how can I configure on Google analytics to track steps made by users on my form. There is a high rate of abandonment on the wizard by mobile devices. The page is responsive, but still I need more information to see where are the users abandoning, which step for example.

Does someone can give me any link that I can find in how to track my wizard form with analytics?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [events](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events?hl=en) or [virtual pages](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications?hl=en) to 'transform' each field in the form and the form-steps to 'virtual urls' you can analyze.

Despite of that, it will be more efficient if you use Google Tag Manager. You can work with the form-steps as individual forms:

- [Form tracking with Google Tag Manager](https://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2014/11/10/form-tracking-google-tag-manager/)
- [Track Form Engagement With Google Tag Manager](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/track-form-engagement-with-google-tag-manager/)